# Tax Implication on loan by NRI to another NRI above INR 30 lakhs

Tags: taxes, income-tax, india, loans, non-resident

I am an NRI in KSA . I paid a loan of 30 Lakhs (interest-free) to my UK friend during FY 2013-14. I paid it 15 lakhs from my NRO A/C and 15 Lakhs from my NRE A/c.

**My fund source in both A/cs is my NRE FUND only**. It is transfers in India from one bank to another bank in India). From my NRO to his NRO & from my NRE to his NRE A/C.

Could you please let me know if there is any TAX Implication in this loan payments.

Awaiting your reply.

rgds,
Davis

Comment: Do you have any paperwork showing that this is indeed a loan? If not, the tax authorities are likely to treat this as a gift from you to your UK friend, Similarly, the repayment of the loan would be a gift to you.

Answer (score 1):

> Could you please let me know if there is any TAX Implication in this loan payments.

Please consult a CA. The regulation is not very clear in such cases. There are regulations for personal loan by NRI to Resident Indian and by Resident Indian to NRI are covered under Foreign Exchange Management Act and Liberalized Remittance Scheme.

There are no explicit regulations on personal loan by NRI to NRI. In my view there shouldn't by any tax implications. However please consult a CA. Keep adequate documentation about this transaction.